# What is the name of the feature of a Router that prompts a user with a webpage when connecting to network?

Tags: router, wireless

The context of this question is for a customer WiFi installation at retail locations.

What I want to achieve is that when a user connects to the network for the first time, a webpage is opened on their device asking them to log in with account (i.e. email or loyalty program).

1. What is the name of this feature so I can make sure the routers we purchase have this feature?
2. Can this webpage send a result (acceptance) to the router so the device is added to a white list?
3. Is this only available for WiFi or can it also be done with Ethernet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time it is called **Captive Portal**. Many WiFi access points or centralized WiFi controller setups support this feature (it may be called differently though).

For ethernet switches there are vendors that support this kind of authentication for example Juniper supports [Captive Portal Authentication](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.4/topics/concept/authentication-understanding-ex-series-switches.html#jd0e99) together with 802.1X and MAC RADIUS authentication on their EX switches.

Answer (score 5):

"Captive Portal"

(you may find it listed in marketing material under other names.)

Answer (score 1):

On Cisco this is called [Authentication Proxy](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_auth/configuration/15-mt/sec-usr-auth-15-mt-book/sec-fwall-https-prxy.html), [Web Authentication Proxy](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless/5500-series-wireless-controllers/113151-web-auth-proxy-00.html), or [Cut-Through Authentication](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/56421/asa-cut-through-authentication-proxy-configuration-and-examples).

Answer (score 0):

Captive portal or splash page, we use them all over in the property I work in....Gaming property in Las Vegas with multiple guest free and pay wifi SSIDs.